# Objective-C How can I code a Wifi disconnection pop up notice?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering if and ow it would be possible to program in Objective-C a code that would automatically send you a notification as soon as you disconnect from your homes wifi ?

Comment: Does it need to be a specific wifi or just any wifi?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at using [SCNNetworkReachability](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/index.html). You can see a good example of this API in use [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_8). You could use this API to schedule a callback which you. I believe you will only get the callbacks when the app is active though, and potentially when the app is resumed.

Answer (score -1):

Using [Apple Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_7) you can create a function to check for the internet connection whenever you want to..

First, you need to download Reachability and added to your project.. then import the .h Reachability file to your view controller where you are going to create your check for internet connection function..

```
+(BOOL)checkForNetworkConnection {

    Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
    Reachability* netReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus wifiStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [netReach currentReachabilityStatus];


    if (netStatus != ReachableViaWWAN && wifiStatus != ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not Network Connection" message:@"Sorry, but there is not network connection." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }

}
```

I have it returning a boolean for simplicity.. I hope it helps! :)